# In Android studio where to find custom templates path

Tags: android, android-studio, freemarker

In Android studio, I am trying to create new Java templates by following the below steps

`Android Studio --> File --> Edit File Template --> Added New file with java extension.-->` Added required code

I am able to use this template for creating new files.
But I want to see this template path.Where these are located?

I can see Android studio predefined templates in `/AndroidStudio/plugin/android/lib/templates` BUT not seeing my newly created templates. Anyone has any idea where new created templates can be found.?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about file templates ?

Comment: @Umair: yes i am talking about file templates

Comment: in my case they are in config folder and path to them is like this:
`C:\directoryName\.YourAndroidStudioVersion\config\fileTemplates`

Comment: did you find them ?

Comment: Nopes i dont see any config folder. using MacOS

Comment: @Umair i dont have this directory win 10, and last stable AS (4.1.1)

Comment: @Aada Are u find it? i didnt find it too:(

Answer (score 5):

1.Navigate to the location of the templates folder :

> `{ANDROID_STUDIO_LOCATION}/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/`

2.On MacOS, this folder was the following:

> `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/`

Comment: what now path for win 10? For last stable AS(Android Studio)?

Comment: There is no templates folder inside lib/ .I am using AS 4.2.2