# How to add new live templates in android studio in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using ubuntu 20.04, and I was recentlly studing the live templates in android studio

but I didn't find the templates folder

I searched every where like this selusion

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177549

or this one

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51647302

or

> https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/tutorial-create-your-own-template-for-android-studio-1aaa9b4cb18

and many other websites, didn't find it

I'm using android studio 4.1

thanks for helping

Comment: Right now, there is no official support for templates, and the old system was replaced by a different system (see [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154531807)). You might want to consider third-party solutions such as [this](https://github.com/hhru/android-multimodule-plugin/blob/master/plugins/hh-geminio/README_EN.md).

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for it.
Instead of copy/paste files in expected directory, you can export from previous android studio version (or create a "settings file" manually).
Then you "just" have to import it as settings.

My "template_settings.zip" contains :

- options
- templates
- "IntelliJ IDEA Global Settings" file
- "installed.txt"

In "templates" folder, you can put a file "MyAndroidLog.xml" containing :

```
<templateSet group="MyAndroidLog">
  <template name="loguw" value="LogUtils.w(BuildConfig.DEBUG, LOG_TAG, &quot;$METHOD_NAME$: $content$&quot;);" description="Custom Log.w(TAG, String) with LogUtils" toReformat="true" toShortenFQNames="true">
    <variable name="METHOD_NAME" expression="methodName()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="false" />
    <variable name="content" expression="" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <context>
      <option name="JAVA_STATEMENT" value="true" />
    </context>
  </template>
</templateSet>
```

Please tell me if it is not clear enough !

Answer (score 0):

### For android studio 4.1 I found the live templates XML in this below path:

IDE configuration directory changes The locations of user configuration directories have been changed to the following:

Windows Syntax: %APPDATA%\Google

Example: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS Syntax: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/

Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux Syntax: ~/.config/Google/

Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

**C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\templates**